# Git extensions standalone UI Tool fails executing any Git command on Windows 11 ARM

Tags: git, apple-m1, parallels, git-extensions

I have a MacBook Pro with M1 chip in which I have virtualized a Windows 11 ARM virtual machine using Parallels 17.

I have installed Git Extensions v3.5.4. When I execute any Git option from it such as Fetch, commit, etc. it always gets stuck.

Git extensions is correctly configured, all the checklist which validates the basic settings needed for Git extensions to work properly are marked as green color. I have no idea why this is happening, maybe because Git Extensions is unstable under a Windows ARM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the settings, disable the use of the 'ConEmu' feature.

https://git-extensions-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/release-3.4/settings.html#git-extensions-advanced-general-use-console-emulator-for-console-output-in-command-dialogs

That's because the external component used to run the git commands by default does not support windows ARM. So you have to disable the feature to let gitextensions launch directly the git process.

Comment: where is exactly the feature 'ConEmu' within the settings? I am not be able to locate it.

Comment: @Ralph I have added a link toward the good option name in GitExtensions documentation....